# Как получить PHAsset видео, если оно еще не сохранено в Photos?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

Как я могу получить PHAsset видео, если у меня есть только URL-адрес, и оно все еще не сохранено, но видео уже снято? Дополнительная информация: Мой пользователь записывает видео - затем я хочу увидеть PHAsset этого видео, а затем он сохранит его (или нет). Я не хочу доставать PHAsset после сохранения видео. Я хочу получить его, прежде чем оно будет сохранен. Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Видео не записывается в оперативную память. Как правило, оно сохраняется в каталоге вашего приложения, и уже после завершения записи фай переносится в фотопленку (например).

поэтому необходимо разобраться с тем как осуществляется завершение записи, и в соответствующий метод делегата вставить вызов плеера и соответствующую обвязку - для удаления, экспорта и т.д.

А каталог и имя файла для записи устанавливаются при инициализации AVAssetWriter.

Comment: у меня уже добавлен плеер. Не понял, что вы имеете в виду под словами добавить соответствующую обвязку.